# Implementation explanation for predict_proba in RandomForestClassifier- sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, probability, implementation, predict

[image: Extract from sklearn documentation of randomForestClassifier]

Attached is an extract from the RandomForestClassifier documentation of sklearn. The last line,"The class probabilities of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf." is something I am not able to grasp, Could someone please help me understand this.!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's explaining how the predict_proba works. If at the lowest level of the tree, you have 80 samples of class 1 and 20 samples of class 0 in a leaf. then the class probability of 1 is 80 / ( total number of class1 samples in the whole population ), and the mean of those class probabilities across all trees is computed. And that's how you get the results from the predict_proba method.

Comment: When we run predict_proba the function doesn’t know the actual classes .. how can there be a (single)leaf that can differentiate between classes in it.

Comment: It does know the classes, when you use predict_proba, the tree has already fit the data, your data points ( to be predicted ) just follow the "path" that the tree drew out of your training data. If your point lands in a leaf where the probability is 0.8, a 0.8 probability will be assigned to it.